# Como juntar 4 tabelas em uma só e mostrar text em vez de INT - INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá, sei que é mais ou menos como esta na 2º print e com o Inner join mas não estou a conseguir.

Estou a usar o MySQL Workbench e mais quando concluir isto quero passar para C#.

Estou com esta duvida, eu ja juntei as 4 tabelas `processos` `tarefas` `tipos` `tecnicos` na tabela `registos`.

Chave primarias são iguais ás estrangeiras, chave primaria de `processos` = `id_processos`, a chave primaria de `tarefas` = `id_tarefas` , a chave primaria de `tipos` = `id_tipos` e a chave primaria de `tecnicos` = `id_tec`.
 A chave primaria de `registos` = `id_registos`.

Agora perciso de ajuda como meter o valor das 4 tabelas em texto em vez de Int.

**NOTA**: Se for perciso mais informação eu dou!

É algo parecido como o 2º Print!

Prints:

[image: Valores base de dados]
[image: É algo deste genero]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não percebi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas para mostrar a relação entre as diferentes 4 tabelas use a seguinte sintaxe:

```
SELECT (tabela1.campo1, tabela2.campo2, ...)
FROM tabela1
INNER JOIN tabela2 on table1.campoRelação= table2.campoRelação
INNER JOIN tabela3 on table2.campoRelação= table3.campoRelação
INNER JOIN tabela4 on table3.campoRelação= table4.campoRelação
```

**Nota:** Se fizer o SELECT dos campos 'ID' vai mostrar os números, caso queira mostrar o 'texto' deverá fazer o SELECT de um campo com o o conteúdo texto.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu perciso usar as 4 tabelas, tecnicos, processos, tipos e tarefas!

Comment: Perciso que ao invez de mostrar o ID como 1 ou 2 (o valor do ID na sua tabela) por exemplo eu escolhi o Adeus que tem o valor 3 em vez de mostrar o 3 mostrar Adeus

Comment: Como eu escrevi na nota, o que vai mostrar depende do que puser dentro dos parêntises do SELECT, se puser o ID, vai mostrar o ID, se puser o campo que contem o "Adeus", irá aparacer esse adeus em vez do ID.

Comment: meu cerebro ta bugado e nao tou conseguindo fazer... tem discord?

Comment: Não... Eu também sou novo nisto, qual é o nome do seu campo que contém o tal "Adeus"?

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa informar a descrição da tabela referente, então ao invés de fazer `p.id_processo` você faz `p.descricao_processo`

```
select p.descricao_processo
      ,t.descricao_tipo
      ,[...]
  from      processos p 
 inner join registros r on r.id_processos = r.id_registro
 inner join tipos     t on t.id_registro  = t.id_tipo
```

**Editado**

Seria +/- isso aqui, agora troque o nome dos campos de acordo com os campos da sua tabela e coloque também os campos corretamente nos joins se precisar...

```
select r.id
      ,r.descricao_registro
      ,p.id
      ,p.descricao_processo
      ,t.id
      ,t.descricao_tipo
      ,ta.id
      ,ta.descricao_tarefa
      ,te.id
      ,t.nome_tecnico
  from      registros r 
 inner join processos p  on p.id_processos = r.id_processo
 inner join tipos     t  on t.id_tipo      = r.id_tipo
 inner join tarefas   ta on ta.id_tarefa   = r.id_tarefa
 inner join tecnicos  te on te.id_tec      = r.id_tec
```

Comment: Eu perciso usar as 4 tabelas, tecnicos, processos, tipos e tarefas!

Comment: Perciso que ao invez de mostrar o ID como 1 ou 2 (o valor do ID na sua tabela) por exemplo eu escolhi o Adeus que tem o valor 3 em vez de mostrar o 3 mostrar Adeus

Comment: Só fazer o inner join com suas 4 tabelas igual você já fez com a tabela REGISTROS e TIPOS, e ao invés de trazer o campo ID destas tabelas, você trás o campo descrição de cada tabela, que seria o campo que possui o "Adeus" como no seu exemplo

Comment: meu cerebro ta bugado e nao tou conseguindo fazer... tem discord?

Comment: Não possuo discord, verifique a edição da minha responsta!

Comment: O que é a descricao e onde criar essa coluna?

Comment: Cara, por favor estude alguma coisa sobre banco de dados antes de fazer perguntas, você precisa saber pelo menos o conceito básico!
Abaixo deixo alguns links:
[link](https://playcode.com.br/banco-de-dados/sql-banco-dados-iniciantes/)
[link](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-select-guia-para-iniciantes/29530)

Comment: Eu ja fiz tudo sobre a base de dados, apenas quem olha para oque tu disseste nao percebe nada, tenta ser mais especifico. Só perguntei se as descrições eram uma nova coluna.

Comment: Pegue esta duas colunas como exemplo `te.id, te.nome_tecnico`....
[te.id - Coluna id da tabela TECNICOS;
te.nome_tecnico - Coluna que possui o nome ou descrição do técnico da tabela TECNICOS;]

Logo, se sua tabela TECNICOS tem as colunas [ID | Nome | Sexo], você faria `te.ID, te.Nome`... Mais claro que isso impossível.

Comment: voce nao percebeu o que eu queria inicialmente, mas obrigado pela ajuda ja foi resolvido.